# How to Purge And Reinstall Syncthing-gtk?

Tags: 18.04, apt, kubuntu

I'm experiencing some issues with `synthing` and `syncthing-gtk`.

I want to completely purge and reinstall it on Kubuntu 18.04LTS.

I tried the usual `sudo apt purge syncthing*`, and this worked rather well, but when I install it again using apt, it still has the configuration data from last time.

How would I completely remove it so that it was like the first time I was installing it?

Comment: Run `locate syncthing` and see what shows up in your home folder and its subfolders. Most likely, there maybe something relevant in `~/.config`.

Comment: I also removed the ~/.config syncthing and syncthing-gtk folders, but no luck :)

Comment: Anything in `~/.cache`?

Comment: I'll have to check. I don't have access to the computer right now. I'll have access to it later tonight.